# Adding layouts to IPE Panels module of Drupal

Tags: layout, drupal

I feel as though this has to be answered somewhere. I am simply trying to add custom page layouts as options to the IPE Panels module of Drupal 8. (see attached)

I cannot find a tut or anything on how to do this. The default layouts do not meet our needs at all.

Looking for a link to a tut or some sort of rundown on "how". Many thanks[image: ![layouts drop down]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWCbj.png)

Comment: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/panels-drupal-8/

Comment: This doesn't explain how to add layout options to the drop down for selection. Thanks, though.